# 12.04 scrolling two finger not working dell 6430u

Tags: 12.04, dell, scrolling

I already set the two fingers scrolling in the preferences however it is not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed on 12.10, but it seemed it will not be fixed on 12.04. See this bug-report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1089413

More Informations here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/opensuse/+bug/606238